# numpy.savetxt without hash mark at beginning of header line

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to save a matrix with header, a hash mark and a space (# ) appear on the first line:

input:

```
np.savetxt(filename,data, fmt='%i %i %i %i %s',delimiter='\t',header="a\tb\tc\td\te")
```

output:

```
# a b   c   d   e
0   0   0   0   bla
0   0   0   0   bla
1   1   1   1   bla
1   1   1   1   bla
```

Any hint why? How could I remove it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

it inserts the # because that line is a comment, and the default character for comments is the symbol #, as you can read in the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

If you want to get rid of it, pass `comments=''` as option to savetxt.