# why there is a "#" in header

Tags: python, header

There is always a `#` in the first column of my header:

```
np.savetxt((self.foldername + '/' + 'XYZ.csv'), XYZ, fmt='%1.6f', delimiter=',',header="X(um),Y(um),Z(nm))
```

I got the header like this

```
#X(um),Y(um),Z(nm)
```

How to avoid the `#`.

Comment: `savetxt` writes the header and footer as comments. To remove the `#`, use [`comments=''`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: However, comment cannot be used to add header. I need a header without #.

Comment: It will still write the header. The parameter `comments=''` will only remove the '#'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant bit from the `loadtxt` docstring describing the `comments` keyword and its effect on the header and other things.

> comments : str, optional
>           String that will be prepended to the `header` and `footer` strings,
>           to mark them as comments. Default: '# ',  as expected by e.g.
>           `numpy.loadtxt`.
>
> ```
>    .. versionadded:: 1.7.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

it inserts the # because that line is a comment, and the default character for comments is the symbol #, as you can read in the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

If you want to get rid of it, pass comments='' as option to savetxt.

from:
[numpy.savetxt without hash mark at beginning of header line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352244/numpy-savetxt-without-hash-mark-at-beginning-of-header-line)