# # getting added to header in csv file

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert a csv file to numpy array. When I'm trying to specify the required column, it just says that it doesn't exist in the csv file. So I checked the csv file and found out that a # is getting added to the header name I specified.
Is there anyway I can avoid that?

Code below

```
np.savetxt(path13 + 'bkg_sample.csv', predictions, fmt = '%5.5f' ,delimiter = ',' , header='predict')
```

Header name - **# predict**

Error on jupyter - **'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'predict'**

```
predict = pd.read_csv('/home/user1/AAAA/Predictions/Code testingbkg.csv',usecols=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

predictions = model.predict(standardscaler.transform(predict))

np.savetxt(path13+'bkg_sample.csv', predictions, fmt = '%5.5f',delimiter = ',',header='predict')

true = pd.read_csv('/home/user1/AAAA/Predictions/bkg_sample.csv')

true[true.predict>0.67] ##This is where the error occurs
```

Links for image:

bkgsample : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0f8Y.jpg

predict.csv : https://i.stack.imgur.com/93lZr.jpg

Comment: Did you try just renaming the columns?
`df.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Yeah tried using `df.rename(columns = {'# predict' : 'predict'})` . Did not work

Comment: Hi can you show us an sample of your predictions array and specify its shape, as well as a sample of the first few lines of your bkg_sample.csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361181/16355784

So apparently it inserts # because the line is a comment, and if you wanna pass it you just need to use `comment=''` in savetxt.

Answer (score 0):

Try listing out columns of your DataFrame:

```
print(true.columns)
```

It looks like in your `bkg_sample.csv` there is no column named `predict` or even `# predict`.

Comment: Says `Index(['# predict']) , dtype = 'object')` when I run this code.

Comment: Have you tried using `true[true['# predict']>0.67]`?

Comment: Also if you want to compare with floats, it would be a great idea to change the dtype of this column to float - `true['# predict'].astype(float)`